# Can't receive updated props after ajax call (react)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Get a func that send data to server

```
addRemark(id,e) {

      var remarktext = this.state.popUpText;
      this.props.addRemark(id,remarktext); // this func sends to serve
      this.props.closePopUp();
      setTimeout(function() { this.props.IncomeListProfile(); }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
```

Now I waiting to update my list with this code
`setTimeout(function() { this.props.IncomeListProfile();`

But I want clearly now, when Data will be added. I create in action that func

```
export function SendedData(data) {
if (data) {
  return {
      type: SENDED_REMARK, data:true
        }
}
}
```

There  I received TRUE. When request good

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {


      var sended = state.getIn(['PopupReducer'])['sendedRemark'];
      console.log(sended + 'true');
      return {

        sended: sended
            };

  }
```

But I can't get true value after I send request, in component I try do

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ sendeder: nextProps.sended });
        console.log('isshwon!!!! ' + this.state.sendeder); //get false every time
      }
```

So Idea is, when I press button "save" I send reqest to server, get response with TRUE, and after that I need update my list

My request using axios

```
export function addRemark(id,remarktext) {

    return dispatch => {

        return (
            console.log(id + remarktext),

            axios.post(Api.getURI("addremark"),{body: {course_id:id, remark:remarktext}}, {
            headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
         }).then(function (response) {


                    //console.log(response.data);
                    dispatch(SendedData(response.data));

                })
            .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                })
            )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer

```
[types.SENDED_DATA] : (state, action) => 
   return { ...state,
      data: Immutable.fromJS(action.d),ata
      isLoading: false
   }
```

Your component

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    return nextProps.data !== this.props.data
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
       //do smthing that you need, data was changed
      this.props.IncomeListProfile();
    }
}
```

Or simply do nothing to rerender component, which rendering based on `data`, as `shouldComponentUpdate` return `true` - it will rerender

Comment: I.m using Redux and axios to send request, is it possible to combine it ? `export function addRemark(id,remarktext) {

 return dispatch => {

  return (
   console.log(id + remarktext),

   axios.post(Api.getURI("addremark"),{body: {course_id:id, remark:remarktext}}, {
   headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
   }).then(function (response) {


     //console.log(response.data);
     dispatch(SendedData(response.data));

    })
   .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
   )
 }

}`

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: Oh, yeah, understand you, so why dont you wont to update your list on `componentDidUpdate` after changing your state via reducer?

Comment: Hm... let I try

Comment: Anywhere, you can access redux state from anywhere, updated the answer

Comment: try do that `componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
          console.log(prevProps);
          if(prevProps.sended !== this.props.sended) {
       //do smthing that you need, data was changed
        this.props.IncomeListProfile();
        }
        } not helps`

Comment: It, works, just first time.. when next time try send nothing happens

Comment: You need to change your `sended` back to false, before you crate next update

Comment: yes... but Where to do this? after  `this.props.IncomeListProfile();` will done?

Comment: Yes, or when, for example you create next request, in reducer of addRemark you can set `sended` to `false`

Comment: Thanks... understand now